# Listing important folders in mutt

Tags: email, mutt

When I type c in mutt I get all my folders displayed and this is quite long.

I would like to configure it to show only those folders that I deem to be interesting. Would be happy to configure it by adding a list in my **.muttrc**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> after <kbd>c</kbd> will switch from the folder to the mailbox list view. Pressing it again takes you back.

You can add new mailboxes with something like

```
mailboxes /some/local/path
mailboxes imaps://some.imap.host/INBOX
```

For imap (after login) this will add  all top-folders to the mailbox list though.

Comment: In my normal muttrc, there is a mailboxes command that adds all the foldes in ~/Maildir/.  If I have run that, how do I empty the list of mailboxes.

Comment: As I understand it, there is no way to "narrow down" the list of folders further (apart from what is already registered as mailbox). Maybe there is some "bookmark" patch available somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [mutt sidebar patch](http://www.lunar-linux.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=44) (available on Debian, Ubuntu and probably others as [mutt-patched](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/mutt-patched) ).

With it, you set up your `mailboxes` as a list of folders you're interested in; they'll appear on the left of the screen. You can then use commands like `sidebar-next` to navigate. I use this setup:

```
bind index \CN sidebar-next
bind index \CP sidebar-prev
bind index \CO sidebar-open
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `mudd-patched`. Do you have any other suggested keybindings for sidebar navigation (e.g., page-up, page-down)? How about searching for a folder and having that folder highlighted in the sidebar)? Or changing whether folders that contain subfolders are expanded/collapsed in the sidebar view? Cheers.